# Switching to iframes in Selenium-Java

Tags: selenium, iframe, xpath

I am not able to switch between the iframes of a window. I want to select an iframe inside the top window of a webpage.

The link of the page is:
http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/dropdown.php#example-1-tab-1

[image]

I can find two iframes but cannot switch to the iframes. Each iframe has their own dropdowns from which I need to select the elements.

I've tried using driver.switchto() but it does not recognizes the iframes.

My code is:

```
    public void SimpleDropDown() throws InterruptedException {
        dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//      dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Select Country']")).click();
//      dr.switchTo().frame(dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='example-1-tab-1']//iframe")));
        Select dropdown = new Select(dr.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/select")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("India");
        System.out.println(dropdown.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
    }

    public void comboBox() {
        dr.switchTo().frame(2);
        dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Enter Country']")).click();
        Select dropdown = new Select(dr.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='combobox']")));
        dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Portugal");
```

Comment: Use `Frame index with 0` for `first frame`

Comment: Target page requires registration, so you'd better provide with appropriate `HTML` code. Also you need `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` before switching to next `iframe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute this code.

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);                                //Move inside to the frame. 
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Enter Country']")).click();
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='combobox']")));
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Portugal");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();                            //Move outside to the frame.
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as Accepted if it's resolved your issue. So it will help for other users as well. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Switching to frames with starting index as 0 works but instead of switching to default frames, should use switchTo().parentFrame() as it goes back to the top window (only if you're not working with nested frames).

Answer (score 0):

Your site is showing 2 `iFrames` in the same page . So before selecting the dropdown you need to switch onto `frame` as your dropdown is under `iframe`-

```
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.tagName("select")));
    select.selectByValue("Angola");
```

Once you have made the selection, need to come out the frame using -

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

and then navigate to the other tab and then again your element is under `iframe` so need to do the same actions again

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/a[text()='Enter Country']")).click();
    driver.switchTo().frame(1);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='custom-combobox']/input")).sendKeys("India");
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```